# What is the correct procedure for opening the cockpit escape hatch on an ATR-72?

Tags: emergency-procedures, atr-72

I’m hoping someone can help me understand the correct procedure for opening the cockpit escape hatch on an ATR-72.

[image]

As I understand it, the operator must hold the rear handle, and pull the forward handle to open the hatch, is this correct?

Does the hatch pivot open, or does it come off completely?

How would one climb out after opening the hatch?

How is the emergency rope used?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I hope you are not asking this because your plane is on fire and you need to get out :p

Comment: @Bianfable Can't even get on a plane right now, let alone one that's on fire

Comment: The image belongs to an [ATR 42-500](https://www.jetphotos.com/photo/7970217). You can see the door opened on an ATR42 [here](http://avherald.com/h?article=46a2b3ac)

Comment: @Rsf is a -42 hatch significantly different from a -72 hatch in look and function? If not, then it probably doesn't matter much. If so, then maybe the OP can find a different picture.

Comment: @Rsf that photo is from an ATR 72-212A (I can confirm, not because I know much about the aircraft, but because I was the one who took the photo!) But it would appear that the escape hatches are not much different. From the reference you provided it looks as if the hatch detaches completely from the fuselage, and is passed out the top?